# Hazelcast Reducer to update map

Tags: mapreduce, hazelcast

I have a reducer that returns an object that is PartitionAware and is supposed to be stored in same partition as other objects it was sourced from, and as I understand, job itself. Does it make sense to update map directly from the Reducer? If it implements HazelcastInstanceAware I can technically access map to store the result. The isea is to minimize cluster traffic.

Comment: What version of Hazelcast ? Do you have scope to upgrade ? If you're on a new enough version, Jet will outperform MapReduce

Comment: Good point, sir! The task I am trying to solve seems to be falling into tumbling kind of stream processing.

Comment: Here's a good place to start, https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples, but just ask more if you need guidance

Comment: Quick question, I couldn't find this in manuals and docs. For example, we have a stream sourced from IMap and the idea is to group objects by some attributes also based on watermark policy, lets say every 500 objects This  can be nicely done with Pipeline API. The question is, all this utility objects used to store partial results, what process/thread ownes them? Trying to understand the performance/memory impact of migration to Jet

Comment: We currently don't support count-based windows, only time-based. Partial results are stored in `HashMap`s, the memory usage is basically _n_ maps mapping key to accumulated value; the _n_ is number of frames: for example, if you have 10 second window sliding by one second and you allow 3 second lag for late events, there will be at least 13 frames.

Comment: Did you find what you're looking for ? For previous queries, what we've sometimes done is collaborated privately to produce a sample solution then published it so everyone can benefit

Comment: I think I am on the right way, just trying to incorporate new concept of infinite stream. It impacts the entire design of the system but I would say in a better way. Where could I post to seek your advise when I have more questions? Community Board presumably?

Comment: Community indeed - try https://gitter.im/hazelcast/hazelcast